# [Query]Grails getLast entry for each groupBy

Tags: hibernate, grails

**Query :  I like to know how one can get latest entry of a domain entity in Grails.**

Problem domain:

```
 class Parent {

    String name
    static hasMany = [children:Child]
}


class Child {

        String name
        Parent parent
        static belongsTo = [parent:Parent]

    }
```

Data model
[image]

**Results**

i like to pull record with id 4 and 7

where critria should be  "get me last record of each parent where child'sname like 'Rox%'

so far i have tried

```
SELECT
MAX(id)
FROM child
WHERE parent_id IN(SELECT
                     p.id
                   FROM parent AS p
                     JOIN child AS c
                       ON (c.parent_id = p.id
                           AND c.name LIKE 'Rox%'))
 GROUP BY parent_id
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: What constitutes "last record"? What is that based upon?

Comment: i have updated question with plain sql query. Perhaps it helps to figure out what actually i am looking for.Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you're using `id` to find the latest record instead of having a `dateCreated` timestamp? The former would seem prone to error.

Comment: im free to use dateCreated if your suggestion work ! Actually i need to have last inserted child object for each parent whcih fulfills criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a tad shady, but I think this is what you want:

```
def idList = [1,4]
def c = Parent.createCriteria()
def result = c.list {
  'in'("id", idList)
  children {
    like("name","Rox%")
  }
  groupProperty("id")
}
```

Edit:

You changed your whole question around while I typed my answer out, changed it around to match.

Final edit:
Add sorting to children {} in the edited code to get the sorting you want.

Comment: Thanks it works. Additionally i am posting proper answer with your further suggestions like 'sorting to children'

Answer (score 0):

```
           Parent.createCriteria().list(max:10,offset:0) {
                     'children' {
                                  like("name","Rox%")
                                  order("id","desc")
                                  groupProperty("id")
                                }


                     groupProperty("id")
              }
```

or

```
     Parent.createCriteria().list(max:10,offset:0) {

                          createAlias("children", "ac")
                          like("ac.name","Rox%")
                          order("ac.id","desc")
                          groupProperty("ac.id")

                     groupProperty("id")
              }
```

where both criteria queries differ with each other on basis of joins. For further reading over joins in criteria
http://adhockery.blogspot.com/2009/06/querying-by-association-redux.html

Answer (score 0):

For that, you need a [SQL window function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function_%28SQL%29#Window_function). In Oracle, that would look like:

```
select max(id)
over(partition by parent_id, order by dateCreated)
from child
group by parent_id
```

There's no way to do it in a single query in Hibernate/HQL.

(you'd also like to get record #9, right?)